# C# - Can't write list into the txt file

Tags: c#

I have a problem with write list into txt file. If I run my Save method it makes only blank txt file. I fill this list from txt file and it works fine so I'm sure it isn't empty(I can see my appointments in calendar). There are my methods.

EDIT

Ok, I know where issue is. _appointments list in Load isn't the same of _appointments list in Save. I don't know why. I don't have any other lists. It's the same but it isn't :/

```
    public bool Load()
    {
        DateTime start = new DateTime(2000,01,01);
        CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        int length = 0;
        string screenDiscription = "";
        bool occursOnDate = false;
        string line;
        int i = 1;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("appointments.txt");

        if (!File.Exists("appointments.txt"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (i % 4 == 1)
            {
                start = DateTime.ParseExact(line, "ddMMyyyy HHmm", enUS);
            }
            if (i % 4 == 2)
            {
                length = int.Parse(line);
            }
            if (i % 4 == 3)
            {
                screenDiscription = line;
            }
            if (i % 4 == 0)
            {
                Appointment appointment = new Appointment(start, length, screenDiscription, occursOnDate);
                _appointments.Add(appointment);
            }
            i++;
        }
        sr.Close();
        return true;
    }

    public bool Save()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("appointments.txt");

        if (File.Exists("appointments.txt"))
        {
            foreach(IAppointment item in _appointments)
            {
                    sw.WriteLine(item.Start);
                    sw.WriteLine(item.Length);
                    sw.WriteLine(item.DisplayableDescription);
                    sw.WriteLine(" ");
            }
            sw.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create("appointments.txt");

            foreach (IAppointment item in _appointments)
            {
                    sw.WriteLine(item.Start);
                    sw.WriteLine(item.Length);
                    sw.WriteLine(item.DisplayableDescription);
                    sw.WriteLine(" ");
            }
            sw.Close();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a `TextWriter` instead of `StreamWriter`?

Comment: using TextWritier would benefit you more.

Comment: @BradleyWilson I thought `StreamWriter` works with bytes, no?

Comment: Try using sw.Flush() before closing the StreamWriter.

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `StreamWriter(string)` constructor says that it will create the file if it does not exist and will throw an exception if it cannot create it.  So, you don't need to check if it exists or create it yourself.

Comment: Yes Stream handles bytes, but TextWritier handles characters. In this case it'll benefit them more with the assumption all input are type String. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010555/io-101-which-are-the-main-differences-between-textwriter-filestream-and-stream

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your `Save` method, but I'm unable to test it as I don't have your `IAppointment` and `Appointment`:

```
public void Save()
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder()
    foreach (IAppointment item in _appointments)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(item.Start);
        builder.AppendLine(item.Length);
        builder.AppendLine(item.DisplayableDescription);
        builder.AppendLine(" ");
    }

    File.WriteAllText("appointments.txt", builder.ToString());
}
```

Note a few things here: I think your `bool` return type is superfluous since the method always returns `true` on all code paths; thus I've changed it to `void`.  Also, I'm using a `StringBuilder` to construct the file contents, and then the built-in `File.WriteAllText` method which abstracts out the IO operations you would normally have to mess around with for opening the stream, the stream writer, closing, etc.

I'm not sure if this will resolve your issue because, as I stated, I can't test it and I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with the code you have, but at the very least it's probably a lot cleaner and easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you for respond. My Save method must be bool because my assingment demand it. I debugged it and there is issue with _appointments list. It's empty. I have no idea why because I load it from file and I can use it in my calendar but when I want to write it into file it's empty..

Comment: "My Save method must be bool because my assingment demand it", if it always returns true I don't really know what to say here!