# In C#, Why can I use TextWriter in place of StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, streamwriter, textwriter

I'm pretty new to C#, so please excuse any questions which seem basic.

I'm wondering why **TextWriter** and **StreamWriter** can both serve the same function (or seem to) in my code example (working with an XML serialization method).

In this example, I'm playing around with a list of XML elements, attributes, etc., and hoping to serialize them by passing them into the *serialize* function (I have created) as a list.

Here's the code ***(notice the use of TextWriter)***:

```
public static void serialize(List<Table> listOfTables)
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Table>));

    TextWriter writer =
        new StreamWriter(@"Location\Sample.xml");

    ser.Serialize(writer, listOfTables);
    writer.Close();
}
```

And here's the code which works exactly the same (or so it seems) ***(notice the use of StreamWriter instead of TextWriter)***:

```
public static void serialize(List<Table> listOfTables)
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Table>));

    StreamWriter writer =
        new StreamWriter(@"Location\Sample.xml");

    ser.Serialize(writer, listOfTables);
    writer.Close();
}
```

As I'm pretty new, I understand the basics of inheritance and abstract classes, but I can't seem to join all the pieces together in order to fully comprehend this.

Please send your thoughts and suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: you have enough information in <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010555/io-101-which-are-the-main-differences-between-textwriter-filestream-and-stream> and <https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f903d07-e07e-49e9-9cee-b52e1dd551ca/textwriter-vs-streamwriter?forum=csharpgeneral>

Answer (score 2):

Both instances are `StreamWriter` instances, but one instance you assign to a variable of the base class type `TextWriter`, which is okay.

Since [`XmlSerialize.Serialize` has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d15aekdk(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts an instance of the base class `TextWriter`, both calls are okay and have the same net effect.